# df.replace on column subset want to keep the full dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Do you know how I could perform this operations but I would like to keep the other columns of the dataframe

```
dfSPSS = dfSPSS.loc[:,'Q2_4_1':'Q2_4_3'].replace(LikertToNum)
```

This code keeps only columns Q2_4_1, Q2_4_2 and Q2_4_3
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
dfSPSS.loc[:,'Q2_4_1':'Q2_4_3'] = dfSPSS.loc[:,'Q2_4_1':'Q2_4_3'].replace(LikertToNum)
```